# customly set button background color ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, colors

I am trying to change the background color of UIButton to a custom color. All the default greycolor, bluecolor, etc do not suffice.

```
    UIColor *myColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0f];
    _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColor];
```

It gives error on 2nd line saying

> ```
> No known class method for selector 'myColor'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine, the simple mistake is again you creted the `[UIColor property]` on second line

```
UIColor *myColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0f];
```

**Not like**

```
  _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColor];
```

**Do like**

```
  _button.backgroundColor = myColor;
```

**Update**

> you can directly use the color property like

```
   _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your current code with below code

```
UIColor *myColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0f];
_button.backgroundColor = myColor;  // because myColor is UIColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 UIColor *myColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0f];
 _button.backgroundColor = myColor;
```

myColor is not defined in UIColor. It's a variable that you defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's much more convenient to use:

```
 _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
```